# How to integrate Machine learning into a ruby on rails application

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, r, ruby, microservices

Given Python and R have huge machine learning libraries that make it easy to train a machine learning model, and given rails provides a very fast way of building a web app, is there a 'best practice' for integrating a machine learning model (written in python or R) into a rails application?

If so what tools can we use? What are pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty of stuff available for Ruby as well, to give you a couple of examples there are

- [Ruby-Spark](https://github.com/ondra-m/ruby-spark) for Apache Spark,
- [Big list of machine learning libraries for Ruby](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning#ruby)
- I can recommend [Classifier-Reborn](https://github.com/jekyll/classifier-reborn) for text classification

And others.

As to calling other languages from Ruby, that's also doable but especially if you need to do it on every request it can be slow. Using Python directly for your entire software might be a better option especially if good performance is required.